# Using .htaccess to NOT rewrite URL's that have a certain GET Parameter

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

The following portion below is written into my .htaccess file. I'm using the ZenCart "CEON URI Mapping" module. I'm having a problem as there is a part of a PHP script that looks for a certain variable and displays a CSS display box when found.

What I need to happen is for htaccess to NOT rewrite URL's with a "amznPmtsOrderIds" GET parameter when set.

How would I incorporate that into the following:

```
# BEGIN CEON URI MAPPING
# Don't rewrite any URIs ending with a file extension (ending with .[xxxxx])
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-z]{2,5}$ [NC]
# Don't rewrite admin directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
# Don't rewrite editors directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/editors [NC]
# Don't rewrite cPanel directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/cpanel [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/frontend [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mp4$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/livehelp.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/rest.php/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/restInterface\.php.*$
# Handle all other URIs using Zen Cart (index.php)
RewriteRule .* index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
# END CEON URI MAPPING
```

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately before this line ...

```
# Handle all other URIs using Zen Cart (index.php)
```

... add this:

```
# Don't rewrite any URIs with a "amznPmtsOrderIds" GET parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !amznPmtsOrderIds [NC]
```